# Step into, step over continue options hidden

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am using latest Vs code version 1.65.2. I am learning python. In my Vs code tool bar, under Run option, step into, step over continue all these options are hidden.I can run the code. But when i try to debug line by line or break point based debugging its not working. It is simply run the code and shows the error or successful run. but not able to stop the running..

I have searched and tried all possible solutions like setting break points, setting stoponenrty: ture on  launch.json file, justmycode: ture, checked key board mapping debugger is current python file etc. but no resolution. If i close all the open project, still its hidden. I see i am basically missing something. but cant figure out. Appreciate your help.

```
Trying to debug, but step by step debug or any form of debug not not working
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's add a breakpoint. The debugger cannot start without a breakpoint.
Then choose the debug[image]

The order from left to right is as follows (with default vs Code shortcut):

```
Continue / Pause F5
Step Over F10
Step Into F11
Step Out ⇧F11
Restart ⇧⌘F5
Stop ⇧F5
```

[image]

Comment: Hi.. tried break point. I just tried on a simple code and big, code the multiple breakpoints. but it didnt work

Comment: When it stops at the breakpoint, it means you can use F10 to run line by line. Can you edit your article and show your debugging process? So I can help you analyze the problem

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the followup. After two weeks of break, i tried today. same error. i deleted all the project folders, just copied only my codes and then created a new separate project folder in desktop path and copied my codes and then its working I can now debug with all the step in, step out options. I dont know what causes the problem, 
 i think may be some file or setting or something which i did in the old project directory is the problem it seems. i tried to replicate the problem again but its not happening. It simply works fine. anyway thanks a lot for the follow up.